# When is mortarboard awarded?

Tags: discussion

I earned 200 rep today, but I don't have mortarboard. Is it awarded at the end of the day, or does it not count the association points I earned for also passing 200 rep total today?

Comment: I don't think it takes the association bonus into account.  If it does, though, all you need to do is be patient.  You'll get the badge.

Comment: Morterboard does take into consideration the association bonus, or at least *did* - I rep capped on my first day because of it (way back when before I had my account re-created)

Comment: @kalina Really? I only *just* got mortarboard and I associated my account about a year ago.

Comment: I don't have enough of my account history left to demonstrate it - it certainly did work that way at some point afaik? Unless I'm missing something your reputation graph only shows you rep capping once

Comment: @kalina nah, I actually got 201 rep today (at time of posting), which was really confusing me too

Comment: it's perfectly possible to get more than 200 rep in a day - that one I can answer and be 100% certain. It's 200 maximum reputation from votes - bounties, accepts, etc do not count towards the cap and allow you to go above 200 rep

Comment: Well, now I'm just confused. Is there an official source to find out how exactly reputation works? Or should I make another question for that?

Comment: @Jason_Berkan that's the only time I've ever seen an edit described as "it's a hat." :) Thank you

Comment: @TheUgly Perhaps you know of [this hat](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qXK41ZrIaoQ/T7Mfa51JtJI/AAAAAAAAGUM/A2v64_tjNt4/s1600/Mortar+Board.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mortarboard does not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178817/154510) the association bonus or points for accepting answers on your questions.

Besides that, most badges that count up actions/posts/etc. are awarded when the UTC day rolls over as kalina mentions.

Comment: Oh jeez, neither? Ok, I didn't even get close then

Comment: But it does include bounties!  That's how I got mine originally.

Comment: Eh, I suck at answering questions, undortunatly. Something I'll have to work on, probably starting with finishing whatever games I start, which I have done maybe once before :|

Comment: @TheUgly The first 200-rep day is almost always a fluke. Some answer of yours gets highly upvoted for some reason, and then a few votes here and there on other, older answers makes up the last few rep to break 200. So, just keep answering questions here and there, and you'll have it strike out of the blue one day. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you earned 200 rep today, it should show up at some point when the scripts that check such things do their magic, but keep in mind the association bonus doesn't count as part of the "hitting the reputation cap" count, and thus doesn't count toward the badge, either.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm that mortarboard does not count the 100 rep association bonus. I only got my badge a week or two ago and I associated my account quite some time ago.

Comment: The association rep bonus is 100 points.